# why are there no atoms with a few protons but many more neutrons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atoms

I saw a graph in a geology class that showed stability fields of elements. something similar to the one below. I noticed there were no elements that had a few protons but tons of neutrons. I was curious why that was so I asked my prof why that was and he also was curious. So now I'm asking you dear reader!! why are there like no stable elements with few protons and many neutrons?

[image]

Comment: Note : that "island of stability" on the top right of your chart is basically guesswork at the moment.  There's no general agreement on where or even *if* it exists.

Comment: $^{7}$H has been observed - one proton and 6 neutrons. It lasts ~5E-22 seconds. $^{10}$He has been observed - two protons and 8 neutrons. It has a lifetime of a whopping ~3E-21 seconds. The neutron (no protons and one neutron) is not stable. Neither is the di-neutron or higher neutron agglomerations.